# trying to send the selected rows primary key into another controller and load the data with that primary key

Tags: java, javafx

Here is the tableview controller :
Trying to send the data associated with the selected row into InstructorProfileContoller, when the button is pressed. The code works and prints you "You selected an Instructor" but then doesn't send any data over

```
    Instructor instructor = (Instructor) InsTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if(instructor != null){
        System.out.println("You select an instructor");
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("InstructorProfile.fxml"));
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("update instructor");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.showAndWait();


        InstructorProfileController instructorProfileController = fxmlLoader.getController();
        instructorProfileController.countrychoicebox.setValue(instructor.getCountryID());
        instructorProfileController.insstatuschoicebox.setValue(instructor.getIns_statusCode());
        instructorProfileController.firstnametextfield.setText(instructor.getIns_firstName());
        instructorProfileController.lastnametextfield.setText(instructor.getIns_lastName());
        instructorProfileController.addresstextfield.setText(instructor.getIns_address());
        instructorProfileController.citytextfield.setText(instructor.getIns_city());
        //  instructorProfileController.dateofBirthpicker.setValue(instructor.getIns_dateOfBirth());
        instructorProfileController.gendertextfield.setText(instructor.getIns_sex());
        instructorProfileController.zipcodetextfield.setText(String.valueOf(instructor.getIns_zipcode()));
    }
    initialize();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method call `stage.showAndWait()` shows the stage, and then waits until it is closed. So you don't set the values until after the user has closed the window. Just move the calls that set the values to before the call to `showAndWait()`.

```
Instructor instructor = (Instructor) InsTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
if(instructor != null){
    System.out.println("You select an instructor");
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("InstructorProfile.fxml"));
    Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();



    InstructorProfileController instructorProfileController = fxmlLoader.getController();
    instructorProfileController.countrychoicebox.setValue(instructor.getCountryID());
    instructorProfileController.insstatuschoicebox.setValue(instructor.getIns_statusCode());
    instructorProfileController.firstnametextfield.setText(instructor.getIns_firstName());
    instructorProfileController.lastnametextfield.setText(instructor.getIns_lastName());
    instructorProfileController.addresstextfield.setText(instructor.getIns_address());
    instructorProfileController.citytextfield.setText(instructor.getIns_city());
    //  instructorProfileController.dateofBirthpicker.setValue(instructor.getIns_dateOfBirth());
    instructorProfileController.gendertextfield.setText(instructor.getIns_sex());
    instructorProfileController.zipcodetextfield.setText(String.valueOf(instructor.getIns_zipcode()));

    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("update instructor");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    stage.showAndWait();

}

initialize();
```

As an aside, it would be a much better style to just define a method `setInstructor(...)` in your `InstructorProfileController`:

```
public class InstructorProfileController {

    // ...

    public void setInstructor(Instructor instructor) {
       countrychoicebox.setValue(instructor.getCountryID());
       insstatuschoicebox.setValue(instructor.getIns_statusCode());
       firstnametextfield.setText(instructor.getIns_firstName());
       lastnametextfield.setText(instructor.getIns_lastName());
       addresstextfield.setText(instructor.getIns_address());
       citytextfield.setText(instructor.getIns_city());
        // dateofBirthpicker.setValue(instructor.getIns_dateOfBirth());
       gendertextfield.setText(instructor.getIns_sex());
       zipcodetextfield.setText(String.valueOf(instructor.getIns_zipcode()));
    }

    // ...
}
```

and then, of course, just do

```
Instructor instructor = (Instructor) InsTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
if(instructor != null){
    System.out.println("You select an instructor");
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("InstructorProfile.fxml"));
    Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();



    InstructorProfileController instructorProfileController = fxmlLoader.getController();
    instructorProfileController.setInstructor(instructor);

    // ...
}
```

That way you don't expose the UI controls outside the relevant controller, which will make your code far more maintainable.

Comment: thank you so much! i thought my code was wrong guess im an idiot